# How to get the original position of the element from the blocks of the list after sorting it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have 4 price lists and 1 deviation list which contains a total of 30 prices and these prices are divided into 5 blocks of 6 elements. They were originally just simply present in the list.

```
price1 =[2, 1, 22, 2, 23, 2, 5, 21, 21, 27, 2, 22, 55, 2, 8, 2, 3, 3, 3, 13, 23, 77, 22, 23, 2, 6, 7, 9, 2, 2]

price2 =[2, 12, 72, 22, 13, 22, 65, 61, 23, 25, 2, 2, 51, 2, 8, 2, 3, 3, 3, 13, 23, 77, 22, 23, 2, 6, 7, 9, 2, 21]

price3 =[21, 52, 72, 22, 93, 32, 85, 61, 23, 25, 2, 2, 51, 2, 8, 2, 3, 31, 3, 13, 53, 67, 23, 83, 2, 16, 74, 19, 2, 11]

price4 =[27, 12, 82, 12, 23, 32, 35, 41, 27, 25, 21, 2, 51, 21, 18, 22, 3, 21, 31, 33, 13, 67, 23, 83, 21, 26, 74, 29, 23, 51]

Deviation =[-17, -2, -2, 52, 13, -32, -15, 71, 27, 25, -221, 21, -151, -21, 128, -22, 312, 212, -31, -533, 13, -227, -123, 183, 21, 26, 74, -129, -23, -21]
```

Now I divided these price-lists into 5 blocks of 6 elements and after that, I get the top 3 highest prices from each block of the list. My approach:

```
n = 6
a = [price1[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(price1), n)]
b = [price2[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(price2), n)]
c = [price3[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(price3), n)]
d = [price4[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(price4), n)]


newPrice1 = [sorted(block, reverse=True)[:3] for block in a]
newPrice2 = [sorted(block, reverse=True)[:3] for block in b]
newPrice3 = [sorted(block, reverse=True)[:3] for block in c]
newPrice4 = [sorted(block, reverse=True)[:3] for block in d]

print("Top 3 Highest Prices in list 1:", newPrice1)
print("Top 3 Highest Prices in list 2:", newPrice2)
print("Top 3 Highest Prices in list 3:", newPrice3)
print("Top 3 Highest Prices in list 4:", newPrice4)
print("Max among all the prices: ", max(newPrice1, newPrice2, newPrice3, newPrice4))
```

output:

```
5 blocks division of price1: [[2, 1, 22, 2, 23, 2], [5, 21, 21, 27, 2, 22], [55, 2, 8, 2, 3, 3], [3, 13, 23, 77, 22, 23], [2, 6, 7, 9, 2, 2]]
5 blocks division of price2: [[2, 12, 72, 22, 13, 22], [65, 61, 23, 25, 2, 2], [51, 2, 8, 2, 3, 3], [3, 13, 23, 77, 22, 23], [2, 6, 7, 9, 2, 21]]
5 blocks division of price3: [[21, 52, 72, 22, 93, 32], [85, 61, 23, 25, 2, 2], [51, 2, 8, 2, 3, 31], [3, 13, 53, 67, 23, 83], [2, 16, 74, 19, 2, 11]]
5 blocks division of price4: [[27, 12, 82, 12, 23, 32], [35, 41, 27, 25, 21, 2], [51, 21, 18, 22, 3, 21], [31, 33, 13, 67, 23, 83], [21, 26, 74, 29, 23, 51]]

Top 3 Highest Prices in list 1: [[23, 22, 2], [27, 22, 21], [55, 8, 3], [77, 23, 23], [9, 7, 6]]
Top 3 Highest Prices in list 2: [[72, 22, 22], [65, 61, 25], [51, 8, 3], [77, 23, 23], [21, 9, 7]]
Top 3 Highest Prices in list 3: [[93, 72, 52], [85, 61, 25], [51, 31, 8], [83, 67, 53], [74, 19, 16]]
Top 3 Highest Prices in list 4: [[82, 32, 27], [41, 35, 27], [51, 22, 21], [83, 67, 33], [74, 51, 29]]

Max among all the prices:  [[93, 72, 52], [85, 61, 25], [51, 31, 8], [83, 67, 53], [74, 19, 16]]

#There is some mistake in getting the max value also because in the second block, there should be 27 instead of 25, 
#similarly, it should be 21 instead 0f 8, 29 instead of 16 in 5th block.
```

Now as you can see the 1st max element is 93 which is in price3 list and originally it was at 4th position, so this 4th position should be searched in `deviation` list, and the element at this position is 13. Similarly, 72 is in price2 and price3 both, so it can return any position, there is no restriction in that, so let's say it took price2 position and it was originally at 2nd position. So the element at 2nd position in deviation is -2 and so on.
My desired output:

```
Deviation = [[13,-2,-2], [-15,71,25], [-151,212,128], [183,-227,13], [74,-129, 26]]
```

I just want the position of those max elements from the prices list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall max calculation is wrong because it only gives you the maximal inner lists - not the maximal column-wise value over all 4 lists.

You can zip the deviation early into your calculations and carry it through -when using sorting/max you specify a key that favours the value and ignores the deviation value carried along:

```
pd1 = list(zip(price1,Deviation))
pd2 = list(zip(price2,Deviation))
pd3 = list(zip(price3,Deviation))
pd4 = list(zip(price4,Deviation))

n = 6
a = [pd1[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(pd1), n)]
b = [pd2[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(pd2), n)]
c = [pd3[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(pd3), n)]
d = [pd4[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(pd4), n)]

newPrice1 = [sorted(block, reverse=True, key = lambda x: x[0])[:3] for block in a]
newPrice2 = [sorted(block, reverse=True, key = lambda x: x[0])[:3] for block in b]
newPrice3 = [sorted(block, reverse=True, key = lambda x: x[0])[:3] for block in c]
newPrice4 = [sorted(block, reverse=True, key = lambda x: x[0])[:3] for block in d]

print("Top 3 Highest Prices/Deviation in list 1:", newPrice1)
print("Top 3 Highest Prices/Deviation in list 2:", newPrice2)
print("Top 3 Highest Prices/Deviation in list 3:", newPrice3)
print("Top 3 Highest Prices/Deviation in list 4:", newPrice4)

rv = []
dv = []
for i in range(len(newPrice1)):
    rv.append([])
    dv.append([])
    for j in range(3):
        m = max(newPrice1[i][j],newPrice2[i][j],newPrice3[i][j],newPrice4[i][j])
        rv[-1].append(m[0])
        dv[-1].append(m[1])

print(rv)
print(dv)
```

Output:

```
Top 3 Highest Prices/Deviation in list 1: [[(23, 13), (22, -2), (2, -17)], 
    [(27, 25), (22, 21), (21, 71)], [(55, -151), (8, 128), (3, 312)], 
    [(77, -227), (23, 13), (23, 183)], [(9, -129), (7, 74), (6, 26)]]

Top 3 Highest Prices/Deviation in list 2: [[(72, -2), (22, 52), (22, -32)],
    [(65, -15), (61, 71), (25, 25)], [(51, -151), (8, 128), (3, 312)], 
    [(77, -227), (23, 13), (23, 183)], [(21, -21), (9, -129), (7, 74)]]

Top 3 Highest Prices/Deviation in list 3: [[(93, 13), (72, -2), (52, -2)], 
    [(85, -15), (61, 71), (25, 25)], [(51, -151), (31, 212), (8, 128)], 
    [(83, 183), (67, -227), (53, 13)], [(74, 74), (19, -129), (16, 26)]]

Top 3 Highest Prices/Deviation in list 4: [[(82, -2), (32, -32), (27, -17)], 
    [(41, 71), (35, -15), (27, 27)], [(51, -151), (22, -22), (21, -21)], 
    [(83, 183), (67, -227), (33, -533)], [(74, 74), (51, -21), (29, -129)]]


[[93, 72, 52], [85, 61, 27], [55, 31, 21], [83, 67, 53], [74, 51, 29]]
[[13, -2, -2], [-15, 71, 27], [-151, 212, -21], [183, -227, 13], [74, -21, -129]]
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this can work fine but there is a mistake in your output too. As I mentioned, when we are calculating the max value then in the 2nd block, max price should be 27(not 25), 3rd block max element should be 55(not 51), 3rd block max should be 21(not 8), in 5th block max element should be 51(not 19) and 29(not 16)

Comment: @nipu Seems you somehow want the column-max? not the max of the inner lists ....

Comment: @nipun - well - simple looping should take care of that. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem, although it looks more lengthy but it works.

```
price1 =[2, 1, 22, 2, 23, 2, 5, 21, 21, 27, 2, 22, 55, 2, 8, 2, 3, 3, 3, 13, 23, 77, 22, 23, 2, 6, 7, 9, 2, 2]

price2 =[2, 12, 72, 22, 13, 22, 65, 61, 23, 25, 2, 2, 51, 2, 8, 2, 3, 3, 3, 13, 23, 77, 22, 23, 2, 6, 7, 9, 2, 21]

price3 =[21, 52, 72, 22, 93, 32, 85, 61, 23, 25, 2, 2, 51, 2, 8, 2, 3, 31, 3, 13, 53, 67, 23, 83, 2, 16, 74, 19, 2, 11]

price4 =[27, 12, 82, 12, 23, 32, 35, 41, 27, 25, 21, 2, 51, 21, 18, 22, 3, 21, 31, 33, 13, 67, 23, 83, 21, 26, 74, 29, 23, 51]

Deviation =[-17, -2, -2, 52, 13, -32, -15, 71, 27, 25, -221, 21, -151, -21, 128, -22, 312, 212, -31, -533, 13, -227, -123, 183, 21, 26, 74, -129, -23, -21]

n = 6
a = [price1[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(price1), n)]
b = [price2[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(price2), n)]
c = [price3[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(price3), n)]
d = [price4[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(price4), n)]


newPrice1 = [sorted(block, reverse=True)[:3] for block in a]
newPrice2 = [sorted(block, reverse=True)[:3] for block in b]
newPrice3 = [sorted(block, reverse=True)[:3] for block in c]
newPrice4 = [sorted(block, reverse=True)[:3] for block in d]

print("Top 3 Highest Prices in list 1:", newPrice1)
print("Top 3 Highest Prices in list 2:", newPrice2)
print("Top 3 Highest Prices in list 3:", newPrice3)
print("Top 3 Highest Prices in list 4:", newPrice4)
print("Max among all the prices: ", max(newPrice1, newPrice2, newPrice3, newPrice4))

#the code that i changed starts from here

max_l=max(newPrice1, newPrice2, newPrice3, newPrice4)
index_l=[]
v=[]
inde=0
inde_1=0
for i in max_l:
    v=[]
    for j in i:
        if j in price1:
            inde=price1.index(j)
            inde_1=Deviation[inde]
            v.append(inde_1)
        elif j in price2:
            inde=price2.index(j)
            inde_1=Deviation[inde]
            v.append(inde_1)
        elif j in price3:
            inde=price3.index(j)
            inde_1=Deviation[inde]
            v.append(inde_1)
        elif j in price4:
            inde=price4.index(j)
            inde_1=Deviation[inde]
            v.append(inde_1)
        else:
            print("not present")
    index_l.append(v)
print(index_l)
```

output:

```
[[13, -2, -2], [-15, 71, 25], [-151, 212, 128], [183, -227, 13], [74, -129, 26]]
```

hope this works for you, let me know if i misunderstood something.

Comment: Thanks it works yes but again there is the same error while calculating the max value among the list. example: Max in the 3rd block will be 55(not 51), 21(not 8), in 5th block 51(not 19), 29(not 16).